# When Wonder Woman says "Hera give me strength", does she get added strength?

Tags: character, dialogue, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited

I'm asking this more due to the animated shows and movies as I haven't seen the recent 2017 Wonder Woman movie. She often says "Hera give me strength." Does she get a power boost, so to speak, or is it more an expression?

One example from the show Justice League Unlimited:

Comment: I always though it was a battlecry, rather than anything that actually enhanced her powers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem that it gives her some extra power boost but rather its more similar to a Battle cry. 
Hera was powerful symbolism for amazons, Hera being most powerful female deity in their beliefs could be the reason. 
By saying those words, Wonder Woman is trying to increase her inner strength and morale and her belief of powerful figure watching over her could give her more confidence in the battle.